# VS Code c плагином python отображает не все подсказки после точки

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

При написании код в VS Code столкнулся с проблемой, что он (VS Code) в подсказках предлагает не все, чем обладает определенный метод. Поправьте пожалуйста если не грамотно написал.

В общем есть строка кода:

```
self.main_window_form.pushButton_1.clicked.connect(self.pushButton_1_clicked)
```

но когда я набрал:

```
self.main_window_form.pushButton_1.click
```

мне не выдало подсказки, что есть еще и clicked !!!
Как решить данную проблему?
Может какие-то настройки поправить или установить расширение?
Может сменить IDE?

Подробнее проблема на скриншоте.
Если будут замечания по коду или советы - с радостью выслушаю.

Есть подозрение, что я не вижу не только метод clicked, а и много другого.
Дело в том, что я только учусь, а такая проблема очень усложняет и задерживает обучение. Например на решение этой проблемы ушло много времени и с чем я еще столкнусь даже боюсь представить.
Чего я еще не вижу и как это узнать?

[image: проблема]

[image: Установленные расширения]

Отправил баг репорт в майкрософт:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17950

Comment: Python - язык с динамической типизацией. Ни одна IDE не может идеально обеспечить подсказки в таком случае. Поэтому решение вашей проблемы одно - страдать. PS: пользуйтесь документацией используемых библиотек, чтобы смотреть, какие члены у них есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще на **Python** в **VisualStudioCode** лучше не писать. Вот среды разработки, которые ***мне*** нравятся:

**1. Wing**

Топовая среда разработки, легко устанавливается, но есть минус - с `tkinter` на ней лучше не работать.

[Сайт установки](https://www.wingware.com/downloads)

**2. PyCharm**

В принципе, хорошая IDE, но трудно устанавливается.

[Сайт установки](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/)

**3. Оригинал - Python IDLE**

Всё хорошо, с графикой нормально, но нет хороших функций, типа подсветки ошибок

[Сайт установки](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/)

Comment: Спасибо за подсказки. Попробую, что скажет PyCharm.
Другие среды не понравились.
Проблему решил совсем по другому.
Возможно топорно и не удобно зато работает.
А именно при помощи qt designer
В нем использую редактор сигналов.
Потом преобразую ui файл интерфейса в py.
Затем переписываю сигнал  свои нужды уже в главной программе
Пока для меня это самый оптимальный вариант

Comment: Попробовал pycharm, но у меня он подтормаживает и темы подсвечивают синтаксис не красиво :-( зато решил проблему

Comment: Ну да, не все тянут `PyCharm`

Comment: Мой комп тоже не тянет :-(

Comment: Нажмите галочку, если ответ Вам помог

Comment: -1000 к карме тому, кто диз поставил! Я же написал, что только учусь! Ты просто скотина и сволочь!

Comment: Всё, я лайк поставил, теперь у тебя 0

Comment: Сравнял счёт)))

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо Питонисту !
Это ошибка криворуких программистов Mirosoft
Отправил баг репорт в майкрософт: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17950
Microsoft выпустило очередное глючное г...но!
Слежу за решением проблемы. Других вариантов кроме как замены среды разработки я пока не вижу.
Можно еще поизвращаться следующим образом.

1. Установить QT Designer.
2. Смотреть что предлагает Signals and slots editor и переписывать под себя в главном коде после конвертации *.ui в *.py при помощи pyside6-uic
   Для меня это пока самый подходящий вариант, потому что pycharm у меня подтормаживает

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ага. В **VisualStudioCode** работают в основном на **C++**